# How do you run a fragment test in a release build?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I'm trying to unit test a fragment using the androidx `FragmentScenario`.

I'm importing `androidx.fragment:fragment-testing` but it appears that is only available for `debugImplementation` import. The unit tests are run against all build variants which causes the fragment tests to fail for `release`.

Has anyone run into this problem before and know of a solution?

Comment: Wrote a post on why this issue happens and some ways around it: https://medium.com/koala-tea-assurance/unit-testing-android-fragments-without-breaking-your-pipeline-66d6c46d7

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution is to use `implementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.2.3")` and ignore the Lint warning. Works like a charm. Googlers [don't seem to bother](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141500106)